# How to mimic an XHR request in Ahrefs.com with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a page that comes from an XHR request. The request is made when the user clicks a link. I've been trying to mimic the request with my scraper, by using the hash in the link's 'onClick' attribute. I can get it to work for the first link, but I need to iterate each of the links on the page. The page itself is behind a login, so I am reproducing as much of what I think is needed below.

The bigger question is this: am I even trying the right thing? Should I use something completely different? Any direction is appreciated.

I am still quite new to this, so my thought is there is perhaps something obvious that I am missing.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    #'content-length':'93',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'cookie':'ajs_anonymous_id=%2254791bca-cf67-4536-bd9e-231dcf9157ef%22; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_user_id=108300; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vwo_uuid_22=654C6CD9AE3842F79BD796977EB8A53F; _vis_opt_exp_22_combi=2; new_RT=1; _vwo_uuid_v2=81F71C91AD0F1AEA7D52FA84E4BCD177|9f489a6cfd5cc6a02bc483a2f51a4a34; intercom-id-dic5omcp=9bfc00e2-1f81-449f-ad47-a79360ad0b5e; _ga=GA1.2.1205864433.1504618215; intercom-lou-dic5omcp=1; PHPSESSID=ldbj3g6tnrq9k8qlekn1813fqc; ljs-lang=en; _gid=GA1.2.895488268.1516275764; intercom-session-dic5omcp=THQ1VW1zT3JpWGRVVitTM0hjbUdMRkRkOGRxamQ5Zkx4VUlrQVNiMkI1VSsxdFIwbTdTbGlrNitGakh4QlRmZC0tRkY3UE10WmxYWldaZVBKT2VGcm9SQT09--5f518888fe0a0a2d6f59fcbc441e827d45674ec0; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImtOM1RIcG50aCtGY0lsZHdQcXVBcEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU1FNM2xsYmhYZXZGRTRlSmNaWmM3SXVZMjZpVzNyWkZRcVdqSm0rcHczd0xRSHJyQnpGbzVOZzlMWUtTaWJyeU5SMWlUUHZCcERZbEVWYUtuOUtaWlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFlOTA1MWE0NjYzM2RiNGQyNTkyMmM2ZmI0MmM1MmE3Y2M2N2M1MTdjYTJiMGY1MTA2NTM1ZmFjZjUwOTRjMzQifQ%3D%3D; ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6ImNPcHF4Sm9LclZTKzh4WEZ1aHlKSnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWHZcLytZTkFUK01XUE9SYWtkOCtlY1dcL1oyWDNlQURINmJ3M25cLzhWXC8yNFwvU3BQVTB2ZU50cG51QnRxeG9nQlFwMjVoa01taUxPYTFsSzVxSEZ3ZEZGUT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGFlNmUzMmQ3ZTQwYzgyM2JmN2U4NzU2NzgwYmY4ZGM0MjZhMDBhYWE1NjY3NGRhYmU1MDIyOTQzOWY4ZWExYiJ9',
    'origin':'https://ahrefs.com',
    'referer':'https://ahrefs.com/link-intersect/result/3/common:desc?linking[0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grandchancellorhotels.com%2Fau%2Fmelbourne%2F&linking[1]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oakshotels.com%2Foaks-on-lonsdale&linking[2]=https%3A%2F%2Fcrossleyhotel.com.au%2F&linking[3]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rydges.com%2Faccommodation%2Fmelbourne-vic%2Fmelbourne-cbd%2F&linking[4]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thehotelwindsor.com.au%2F&linking[5]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spacehotel.com.au%2F&linking[6]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stamford.com.au%2Fspm%2F&linking[7]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citadines.com%2Fen%2Faustralia%2Fmelbourne%2Fcitadines-on-bourke-melbourne%2F&linking[8]=https%3A%2F%2Fmelbourne.grand.hyatt.com&linking[9]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somerset.com%2Faustralia%2Fmelbourne%2Fsomerset-on-elizabeth-melbourne%2F&linking-modes[0]=prefix&linking-modes[1]=prefix&linking-modes[2]=subdomains&linking-modes[3]=prefix&linking-modes[4]=subdomains&linking-modes[5]=subdomains&linking-modes[6]=prefix&linking-modes[7]=prefix&linking-modes[8]=prefix&linking-modes[9]=prefix&no-linking[0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marriott.com%2Fhotels%2Ftravel%2Fmelmc-melbourne-marriott-hotel%2F&no-linking-modes[0]=prefix&is_union=1',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token':'kbIUUA1ygDlENDGohYxYbEhLPUVZZBIR2hWOcGoB',
    'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'
}
data={
    'for_domain':'cityaccommodations.com.au',
    'domain_index':101,
    'target_index':3,
    'offset':0,
    'count':0,
    'total_count':4
}

r = requests.post('https://ahrefs.com/site-explorer/ajax/examples/backlinks-for-intersect-domain/d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14', headers=headers, data=data)
response = r.text
python_object = json.loads(response)
print(python_object)
for item in python_object:
    print(item)
    for thing in item:
        print(".   " + thing)
print(r.text)
```

It doesn't error, but the JSON returned has an empty array for 'result', and I noticed 'cache-expired' is True. The JSON returned, if it works properly, would be:

```
{"examples_data":{"result":[{"url_from":"http:\/\/cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","ahrefs_rank":8,"domain_rating":45,"ahrefs_top":0,"ip_from":"182.50.132.56","links_internal":"14","links_external":"7","page_size":"5 kB","encoding":"iso-8859-1","title":"The Crossley Hotel Managed by Mecure - Accommodation - Melbourne City, Little Bourke St, Melbourne","language":"en","url_to":"https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","first_seen":"27 Jun '17","last_visited":"16 Jan '18","prev_visited":"1 Dec '17","original":false,"redirect":0,"alt":"","anchor":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","text_pre":"Website:","text_post":"","http_code":200,"url_from_first_seen":"2016-01-23T19:23:54Z","first_origin":"recrawl","last_origin":"recrawl","sitewide":false,"link_type":"Nofollow","nofollow":true,"number":1,"type":"","powered_by":[],"WidthAhrefsRank":0,"IsRedirectChain":false,"rows_limit_not_exceeded":true,"authorized_user":true,"free_user":false,"lite_user":false,"standard_user":false,"free_or_lite_user":false,"free_or_lite_or_standard_user":false,"position_limit_not_exceeded":true,"Visited":"16 Jan '18","TimeAgoSecond":true,"VisitedLess2Days":false,"VisitedMore2Days":true,"VisitedLess1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Month":false,"VisitedDays":3,"VisitedHours":0,"VisitedMinutes":0,"new_ref_page":true,"curr_ref_page":false,"curr_ref_page_number":1,"empty_anchor":false,"show_anchor":true,"space_between_anchor_and_post":" ","http_code_name":"ok","https_url_from":false,"prepared_url_from":"http:\/\/cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","https_url_to":true,"prepared_url_to":"https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","url_from_Parts":true,"url_from_Part2":"cityaccommodations.com.au","url_from_Part3":"\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","url_to_Parts":true,"url_to_Part2":"crossleyhotel.com.au","url_to_Part3":"\/","isJsRendered":false,"StatusDropped":false,"StatusPageRedirected":false,"StatusPageNoIndex":false,"StatusPageNonCanonical":false,"StatusLinkRemoved":false,"StatusLinkBrokenRedirect":false,"DateDeleted":false,"backlink_status":"","isLost":true,"deleted_at":"","empty_domain_rank":false,"low_domain_rank":true,"middle_domain_rank":false,"height_domain_rank":false,"DomainRating":45,"ExampleUniqueId":"101_domain3_1","ExampleTRId":"tr_example_backlinks","Language":"English","SocialMediaURLHash":"63bb0d959c467f5828824e310bb87690","available_social_media":true,"not_available_social_media":false},{"url_from":"http:\/\/cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","ahrefs_rank":8,"domain_rating":45,"ahrefs_top":0,"ip_from":"182.50.132.56","links_internal":"14","links_external":"7","page_size":"5 kB","encoding":"iso-8859-1","title":"The Crossley Hotel Managed by Mecure - Accommodation - Melbourne City, Little Bourke St, Melbourne","language":"en","url_to":"https:\/\/www.crossleyhotel.com.au\/","first_seen":"21 Apr '17","last_visited":"16 Jan '18","prev_visited":"1 Dec '17","original":false,"redirect":0,"alt":"","anchor":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","text_pre":"Website:","text_post":"","http_code":200,"url_from_first_seen":"2016-01-23T19:23:54Z","first_origin":"recrawl","last_origin":"recrawl","sitewide":false,"link_type":"Nofollow","nofollow":true,"number":2,"type":"","powered_by":[],"WidthAhrefsRank":0,"IsRedirectChain":false,"rows_limit_not_exceeded":true,"authorized_user":true,"free_user":false,"lite_user":false,"standard_user":false,"free_or_lite_user":false,"free_or_lite_or_standard_user":false,"position_limit_not_exceeded":true,"Visited":"16 Jan '18","TimeAgoSecond":true,"VisitedLess2Days":false,"VisitedMore2Days":true,"VisitedLess1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Month":false,"VisitedDays":3,"VisitedHours":0,"VisitedMinutes":0,"new_ref_page":false,"curr_ref_page":true,"curr_ref_page_number":1,"empty_anchor":false,"show_anchor":true,"space_between_anchor_and_post":" ","http_code_name":"ok","https_url_from":false,"prepared_url_from":"http:\/\/cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","https_url_to":true,"prepared_url_to":"https:\/\/www.crossleyhotel.com.au\/","url_from_Parts":true,"url_from_Part2":"cityaccommodations.com.au","url_from_Part3":"\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","url_to_Parts":true,"url_to_Part2":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","url_to_Part3":"\/","isJsRendered":false,"StatusDropped":false,"StatusPageRedirected":false,"StatusPageNoIndex":false,"StatusPageNonCanonical":false,"StatusLinkRemoved":false,"StatusLinkBrokenRedirect":false,"DateDeleted":false,"backlink_status":"","isLost":true,"deleted_at":"","empty_domain_rank":false,"low_domain_rank":true,"middle_domain_rank":false,"height_domain_rank":false,"DomainRating":45,"ExampleUniqueId":"101_domain3_2","ExampleTRId":"tr_example_backlinks","Language":"English","SocialMediaURLHash":"63bb0d959c467f5828824e310bb87690","available_social_media":true,"not_available_social_media":false},{"url_from":"http:\/\/www.cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","ahrefs_rank":8,"domain_rating":45,"ahrefs_top":0,"ip_from":"182.50.132.56","links_internal":"14","links_external":"7","page_size":"5 kB","encoding":"iso-8859-1","title":"The Crossley Hotel Managed by Mecure - Accommodation - Melbourne City, Little Bourke St, Melbourne","language":"","url_to":"https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","first_seen":"14 Jul '17","last_visited":"11 Dec '17","prev_visited":"9 Nov '17","original":false,"redirect":0,"alt":"","anchor":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","text_pre":"Website:","text_post":"","http_code":200,"url_from_first_seen":"2013-08-10T21:38:52Z","first_origin":"recrawl","last_origin":"recrawl","sitewide":false,"link_type":"Nofollow","nofollow":true,"number":3,"type":"","powered_by":[],"WidthAhrefsRank":0,"IsRedirectChain":false,"rows_limit_not_exceeded":true,"authorized_user":true,"free_user":false,"lite_user":false,"standard_user":false,"free_or_lite_user":false,"free_or_lite_or_standard_user":false,"position_limit_not_exceeded":true,"Visited":"11 Dec '17","TimeAgoSecond":true,"VisitedLess2Days":false,"VisitedMore2Days":false,"VisitedLess1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Month":true,"VisitedDays":0,"VisitedHours":0,"VisitedMinutes":0,"new_ref_page":true,"curr_ref_page":false,"curr_ref_page_number":3,"empty_anchor":false,"show_anchor":true,"space_between_anchor_and_post":" ","http_code_name":"ok","https_url_from":false,"prepared_url_from":"http:\/\/www.cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","https_url_to":true,"prepared_url_to":"https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","url_from_Parts":true,"url_from_Part2":"www.cityaccommodations.com.au","url_from_Part3":"\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","url_to_Parts":true,"url_to_Part2":"crossleyhotel.com.au","url_to_Part3":"\/","isJsRendered":false,"StatusDropped":false,"StatusPageRedirected":false,"StatusPageNoIndex":false,"StatusPageNonCanonical":false,"StatusLinkRemoved":false,"StatusLinkBrokenRedirect":false,"DateDeleted":false,"backlink_status":"","isLost":true,"deleted_at":"","empty_domain_rank":false,"low_domain_rank":true,"middle_domain_rank":false,"height_domain_rank":false,"DomainRating":45,"ExampleUniqueId":"101_domain3_3","ExampleTRId":"tr_example_backlinks","Language":false,"SocialMediaURLHash":"0a29309c991ccbb6c4cbc8884a5274e0","available_social_media":true,"not_available_social_media":false},{"url_from":"http:\/\/www.cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","ahrefs_rank":8,"domain_rating":45,"ahrefs_top":0,"ip_from":"182.50.132.56","links_internal":"14","links_external":"7","page_size":"5 kB","encoding":"iso-8859-1","title":"The Crossley Hotel Managed by Mecure - Accommodation - Melbourne City, Little Bourke St, Melbourne","language":"","url_to":"https:\/\/www.crossleyhotel.com.au\/","first_seen":"3 May '17","last_visited":"11 Dec '17","prev_visited":"9 Nov '17","original":false,"redirect":0,"alt":"","anchor":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","text_pre":"Website:","text_post":"","http_code":200,"url_from_first_seen":"2013-08-10T21:38:52Z","first_origin":"recrawl","last_origin":"recrawl","sitewide":false,"link_type":"Nofollow","nofollow":true,"number":4,"type":"","powered_by":[],"WidthAhrefsRank":0,"IsRedirectChain":false,"rows_limit_not_exceeded":true,"authorized_user":true,"free_user":false,"lite_user":false,"standard_user":false,"free_or_lite_user":false,"free_or_lite_or_standard_user":false,"position_limit_not_exceeded":true,"Visited":"11 Dec '17","TimeAgoSecond":true,"VisitedLess2Days":false,"VisitedMore2Days":false,"VisitedLess1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Hour":false,"VisitedMore1Month":true,"VisitedDays":0,"VisitedHours":0,"VisitedMinutes":0,"new_ref_page":false,"curr_ref_page":true,"curr_ref_page_number":3,"empty_anchor":false,"show_anchor":true,"space_between_anchor_and_post":" ","http_code_name":"ok","https_url_from":false,"prepared_url_from":"http:\/\/www.cityaccommodations.com.au\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","https_url_to":true,"prepared_url_to":"https:\/\/www.crossleyhotel.com.au\/","url_from_Parts":true,"url_from_Part2":"www.cityaccommodations.com.au","url_from_Part3":"\/Melbourne_accommodations\/The_Crossley_Hotel_Managed_by_Mecure\/Accommodation\/1378","url_to_Parts":true,"url_to_Part2":"www.crossleyhotel.com.au","url_to_Part3":"\/","isJsRendered":false,"StatusDropped":false,"StatusPageRedirected":false,"StatusPageNoIndex":false,"StatusPageNonCanonical":false,"StatusLinkRemoved":false,"StatusLinkBrokenRedirect":false,"DateDeleted":false,"backlink_status":"","isLost":true,"deleted_at":"","empty_domain_rank":false,"low_domain_rank":true,"middle_domain_rank":false,"height_domain_rank":false,"DomainRating":45,"ExampleUniqueId":"101_domain3_4","ExampleTRId":"tr_example_backlinks","Language":false,"SocialMediaURLHash":"0a29309c991ccbb6c4cbc8884a5274e0","available_social_media":true,"not_available_social_media":false}],"Allow":true,"APIURLHash":"1e52c833a6961148516eadc7c536c81c","projectPath":"\/site-explorer","AnchorIndex":0,"DomainIndex":101,"SnippetIndex":0,"URLIndex":0,"AggregatorIndex":0,"TargetIndex":3,"Count":10,"ForAnchor":"","ForDomain":"cityaccommodations.com.au","ForSnippet":"","ForURL":"https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","ForAggregator":"","Offset":0,"TotalCount":4,"CachedSecurityHash":"d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14","DateFrom":"","DateTo":"","ExamplesDataType":"backlinks_for_intersect_domain","DataType":"backlinks_for_intersect_domain","MaxAhrefsRank":0,"AvailableDisavowLinks":false,"DashboardID":false,"DisavowInterface":false,"DefaultHistoryMode":"recent","HistoryMode":"recent","DataRowsLeft":5000000,"linkExtIntType":"","linkForExport":"https:\/\/ahrefs.com\/site-explorer\/ajax\/examples\/backlinks-for-intersect-domain\/d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14?for_domain=cityaccommodations.com.au&domain_index=101&target_index=3","ReferringDomainsHistoryExamples":false,"ReferringDomainsNewExamples":false,"ExamplesModeAnchors":false,"ExamplesModeDomains":false,"ExamplesModeSnippets":false,"ExamplesModeLinkedAnchors":false,"ExamplesModeTopContent":false,"ExamplesModeIntersect":true,"SELinkBacklinks":"\/site-explorer\/backlinks\/v5\/external\/exact\/recent\/all\/all\/1\/ahrefs_rank_desc?target=https:\/\/crossleyhotel.com.au\/","social_media":"99e442558b5cc604a33f8818bff91601"},"examples_html":"<div id=\"data_for_examples_container_101_domain3\" class=\"bg-lightblue intable relative p-x-2 m-b-2\">\n                <table class=\"table table-ahrefs intable bg-lightblue b-b-1px\" id=\"examples_table_101_domain3\">\n                <tbody>\n                    <tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-2 p-l-0\">Referring page<\/th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-01\" title=\"Domain rating\">DR<\/th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-01\" title=\"URL rating\">UR<\/th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-01\" title=\"External links\">Ext.<\/th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-2 p-l-0\">Anchor and backlink<\/th>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"width-001 text-nowrap text-xs-left p-r-0\">First seen<br> Last check<\/th>\n                    <\/tr>\n                <\/tbody>\n                <\/table>\n            <\/div>\n\t\t    \n<div class=\"clearfix\"><\/div>","examples_footer_html":"<div class=\"examples-footer\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"p-x-2 view-more-group m-b-2\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class=\"view-more border-right list-inline-item\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\" title=\"Hide All\"\n\t\t\t\t   onclick=\"if ($('#examples_backlinks_container_101_domain3').length > 0) { $('#get_backlinks_link_101_domain3').click(); }\">\n\t\t\t\t\tHide All\n\t\t\t\t<\/a>\n\t\t\t\t<a class=\"clickable all__link\" title=\"Export all data in CSV\" data-limit=\"4\" onclick=\"CheckExportTimeout({link: 'https:\/\/ahrefs.com\/site-explorer\/ajax\/examples\/backlinks-for-intersect-domain\/d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14?for_domain=cityaccommodations.com.au&amp;domain_index=101&amp;target_index=3', hash: '1e52c833a6961148516eadc7c536c81c', need_rows: 4, rawExportLeft: 5000000, limit_obj: this});\">\n    <span class=\"icon icon--export colored\"><\/span> Export\n<\/a>\n\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t<\/div>\n\t","cache_expired":false}
```

Here is the link that, when clicked, makes the XHR request:

```
<a href="javascript:void(null);" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sec-trans btn-sm dropdown-toggle" id="get_backlinks_link_101_domain3" title="Show backlinks" onclick="ShowHideBacklinksExamples({Hash: 'd72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14', ForDomain: 'cityaccommodations.com.au', DomainIndex: 101, TargetIndex: 3, TotalCount: 4, Offset: 0, LinkObj: this});">4</a>
```

In dev tools, under Network, here is the content of the request:

General:

```
Request URL:https://ahrefs.com/site-explorer/ajax/examples/backlinks-for-intersect-domain/d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:151.80.39.61:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers:

```
cache-control:private, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:2419
content-type:application/json
date:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 19:13:57 GMT
expires:-1
pragma:no-cache
server:nginx/1.10.3
set-cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IitNYmwxa1FTS29LdXEwd2xPWFpXTHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicXBLSmxvMWJ1TCttdTBCV0R3ZWNZNkZBRzduVjcwaXpXbFdPY0JoaHRIXC9hQXRpNVBKYkc4RFZRWWtSUEM4T3NTclwvQTBWNFkxUXZSXC9NVlVQR0ZSTmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjNlNWE2NGU4NDViZDI4ZGNlNjZlNTVmYzFjYWMyOTllYTgyMThmZTc0OTY3YjAwYjhmZTdmOGI2MDE5MWMzNDQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 19:13:57 GMT; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com
set-cookie:ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6IjJZZnI3bUcxNU9BUk51VnRYV2piaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidDZzV2VzMWloQ3BxeVI5eFQ3TFR0NVYybmVCdTdvVFBIMzJGNTMxMEFJclV1OFh5ZlBaeFRoY3d0cWxvYmExbnh1THAzTk9salZ0cXd0QTRadDZRWUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjQ5OTBiY2ExNDM1YjE1MzE4Nzc4MmNhZDRhNThhN2JmN2M2N2M2NWU1NWFlNGVhMThhOWY3NWM4NmEyZWFmZGMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 19:13:57 GMT; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com; HttpOnly
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Request Headers:

```
:authority:ahrefs.com
:method:POST
:path:/site-explorer/ajax/examples/backlinks-for-intersect-domain/d72718a2895587e32a5a869c3858df14
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length:99
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie:ajs_anonymous_id=%2254791bca-cf67-4536-bd9e-231dcf9157ef%22; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_user_id=108300; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vwo_uuid_22=654C6CD9AE3842F79BD796977EB8A53F; _vis_opt_exp_22_combi=2; new_RT=1; _vwo_uuid_v2=81F71C91AD0F1AEA7D52FA84E4BCD177|9f489a6cfd5cc6a02bc483a2f51a4a34; intercom-id-dic5omcp=9bfc00e2-1f81-449f-ad47-a79360ad0b5e; _ga=GA1.2.1205864433.1504618215; intercom-lou-dic5omcp=1; PHPSESSID=ldbj3g6tnrq9k8qlekn1813fqc; ljs-lang=en; _gid=GA1.2.895488268.1516275764; intercom-session-dic5omcp=THQ1VW1zT3JpWGRVVitTM0hjbUdMRkRkOGRxamQ5Zkx4VUlrQVNiMkI1VSsxdFIwbTdTbGlrNitGakh4QlRmZC0tRkY3UE10WmxYWldaZVBKT2VGcm9SQT09--5f518888fe0a0a2d6f59fcbc441e827d45674ec0; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImtOM1RIcG50aCtGY0lsZHdQcXVBcEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU1FNM2xsYmhYZXZGRTRlSmNaWmM3SXVZMjZpVzNyWkZRcVdqSm0rcHczd0xRSHJyQnpGbzVOZzlMWUtTaWJyeU5SMWlUUHZCcERZbEVWYUtuOUtaWlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFlOTA1MWE0NjYzM2RiNGQyNTkyMmM2ZmI0MmM1MmE3Y2M2N2M1MTdjYTJiMGY1MTA2NTM1ZmFjZjUwOTRjMzQifQ%3D%3D; ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6ImNPcHF4Sm9LclZTKzh4WEZ1aHlKSnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWHZcLytZTkFUK01XUE9SYWtkOCtlY1dcL1oyWDNlQURINmJ3M25cLzhWXC8yNFwvU3BQVTB2ZU50cG51QnRxeG9nQlFwMjVoa01taUxPYTFsSzVxSEZ3ZEZGUT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGFlNmUzMmQ3ZTQwYzgyM2JmN2U4NzU2NzgwYmY4ZGM0MjZhMDBhYWE1NjY3NGRhYmU1MDIyOTQzOWY4ZWExYiJ9
origin:https://ahrefs.com
referer:https://ahrefs.com/link-intersect/result/3/common:desc?linking[0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grandchancellorhotels.com%2Fau%2Fmelbourne%2F&linking[1]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oakshotels.com%2Foaks-on-lonsdale&linking[2]=https%3A%2F%2Fcrossleyhotel.com.au%2F&linking[3]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rydges.com%2Faccommodation%2Fmelbourne-vic%2Fmelbourne-cbd%2F&linking[4]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thehotelwindsor.com.au%2F&linking[5]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spacehotel.com.au%2F&linking[6]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stamford.com.au%2Fspm%2F&linking[7]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.citadines.com%2Fen%2Faustralia%2Fmelbourne%2Fcitadines-on-bourke-melbourne%2F&linking[8]=https%3A%2F%2Fmelbourne.grand.hyatt.com&linking[9]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somerset.com%2Faustralia%2Fmelbourne%2Fsomerset-on-elizabeth-melbourne%2F&linking-modes[0]=prefix&linking-modes[1]=prefix&linking-modes[2]=subdomains&linking-modes[3]=prefix&linking-modes[4]=subdomains&linking-modes[5]=subdomains&linking-modes[6]=prefix&linking-modes[7]=prefix&linking-modes[8]=prefix&linking-modes[9]=prefix&no-linking[0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marriott.com%2Fhotels%2Ftravel%2Fmelmc-melbourne-marriott-hotel%2F&no-linking-modes[0]=prefix&is_union=1
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token:kbIUUA1ygDlENDGohYxYbEhLPUVZZBIR2hWOcGoB
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

Form Data:

```
for_domain:cityaccommodations.com.au
domain_index:101
target_index:3
offset:0
count:0
total_count:4
```

Comment: `XHR` is normal request - sometimes portals only check if there is header `x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: you should use `requests.Session()` to automatically get/use `cookies`. You can also do `GET` requests before `POST` to get all values in hidden fields - they can be different in every request (the same as cookies).

Comment: @furas thanks, so I need to use a `GET` request to figure out what the cookie in my `POST` request needs to be, and then use `requests.Session()` to update the cookie, and then make the `POST` request?

Comment: you can use `s = requests.Sessions()` and then `s.get()` and `s.post()` and it will use cookies automatically and you don't have to copy cookies.